# Maximize a windows application that is running

Tags: python, windows

i am making an script for automating some task.

I want to maximize a windows application (bluestacks) that i will have already running and minimized. I want to maximize it so then i can make some clicks, etc on that window.

How can i do that?

Comment: Here are a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344140/is-there-a-way-to-minimize-a-window-in-windows-7-via-python-3) search [results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790825/how-can-i-maximize-a-specific-window-with-python).