# Is there a way to minimize the python console after launching it?

Tags: python

Yes converting the python file to .pyw hides it but I only want it to be minimized and still access it.

Comment: This seems to answer it:
[Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245520/is-it-possible-to-minimize-the-console-in-python-with-the-standard-librairy-wit)